# How to refresh data from Room when using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I have a few items stored in Room, and I want to add a new one. Here is what I have tried:

```kotlin
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
    fun getItems(): List<Intem>

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    fun addItem(item: Item)
}
```

My repo is very simple:

```kotlin
interface ItemRepository {
    fun getItemsFromRoom(): List<Item>

    fun addItemToRoom(item: Item)
}
```

And inside the View Model class I do:

```kotlin
class ItemsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var items by mutableStateOf(emptyList<Item>())

    fun getItems() = viewModelScope.launch {
        items = repo.getItemsFromRoom()
    }

    fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.addItemToRoom(ietm)
    }
}
```

And inside the composable I do:

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    items(
       items = viewModel.items
    ) { item ->
        Text(item.name)
    }
}
```

When I open the app, I get all the data from Room correctly. When I want to add another item, I press a button, a dialog is displayed, I write the data and I hit add. The problem comes when the dialog is closed, I cannot see the new data, unless I close and reopen the app. Why isn't the state changed when I add a new item in Room? How to solve this?

Comment: *Why isn't the state changed* **that's how room works when query is returning `List<T>`** .... you need to return some observable class of the list ... depends on your needs(i'm not familiar with compse/kotlin so for me in java `LiveData<List<T>>` works fine) ... I'm pretty sure that in official room's documentation is written what options you have

Comment: @Selvin Hi Selvin. Thanks for commenting. I saw that approach, but LiveData [observe](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,kotlin.Function1)) is now deprecated. Any other ideas?

Comment: But there is `fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<Any!>): Unit` which is not deprecated ... the only deprecated is extension method ... the point is to check the official docs

Comment: @Selvin Thanks Sevin. So that's the single solution? I couldn't see that in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: for kotlin prolly flow is the option ... but again it's easy to find in offical docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should emit a reactive data stream (like `LiveData` or `Flow`) from your Dao if you want to get data updates. It's better to use a `Flow` here.

```kotlin
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Intem>>

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    fun addItem(item: Item)
}

interface ItemRepository {
    fun getItemsFromRoom(): Flow<List<Item>>

    fun addItemToRoom(item: Item)
}
```

And in your ViewModel, you don't need a new `getItems` function to be called from the UI. Instead you can directly do this:

```kotlin
class ItemsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val items = repo.getItemsFromRoom()

    fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.addItemToRoom(ietm)
    }
}
```

Finally, in the UI, you can collect this Flow like this:

```kotlin
val items by viewModel.items.collectAsState(initialValue = emptyList())
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    items(items = items) { item ->
        Text(item.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Arpit. Let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: One more quick question. Do I need to use LaunchedEffect when calling items from the ViewModel?

Comment: No, you don't. `items` isn't a function. You are only accessing a variable.

Comment: So, it won't be called multiple times while recomposition?

Comment: It will be called, but getting the value of a variable isn't a heavy task.

Comment: But when calling a function, it is? That's why we need to add it into a LaunchedEffect block?

Comment: Yeah, if you want the function to be called only once (and not every recomposition), you call it inside `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: And the last question, in case of a variable there's no need for any other operation, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you are only fetching the value of a variable, you can fetch it directly inside composition scope. In this, `collectAsState` will be called on every recomposition, but I guess it is fine because it has been designed to be called from a composition scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your query returns `List` of items. To refresh UI list you need to call `getItemsFromRoom` function again. It's not updated automatically because it's only simple `List`.
I would suggest to return `Flow<List<Item>>` instead of `List<Item>` and collect from that flow to update items automatically then database changes

Where's official android [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow#0), where you can follow step by step to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Selvin said it's best LiveData from a Java perspective, but you say Flow. I'll go with Flow as it seems to be more appropriate. Can show me a quick example please?

Comment: @JoanP. I updated my answer with android codelab example.

Comment: I'm really confused right now. In the code lab, the `fun getAll(): List<Schedule>` returns a `List<Schedule>` as my function returns `List<Item>`, I cannot see any difference at all. Besides that, I cannot see any flow as in your answer, nor something related to Jetpack Compose :(

Comment: @JoanP. For flow part check #9 Step of codelab

Comment: Let me check that and get back to you. If it solves the problem, I'll wait 1-2 days, and if I won't get a better one, I will accept yours. Thanks.